# are there any cocoa application samples installed on mac along with xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have installed xcode 4.3 on mac osx lion, are there any cocoa application samples installed on the disk along with xcode ? I could not locate them, can someone please advise me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the documentation with the documentation browser in the "organizer" then you'll find links for the various sample projects. The link should say "Open Project..." and that'll download the project and open it.

As far as I know though, the sample projects are all downloaded as you want them. This is quite good though as it means you're not shipped a load of sample projects, most of which will never get opened, when you download Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the documentation from within Xcode the files are already on your hard disk.

1. Navigate Finder to `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`
2. Make a right click on `com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset` and choose `Show Package Contents`
3. Open the Folder `Contents/Resources/Documents/samplecode`

Or open a terminal and use 
`open ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/samplecode/`